# Angular 6 : where getting error module "rxjs/add/operator/map" and another error 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'

Tags: angular, npm, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am using Angular 6 where I am getting two errors -

1. ERROR in ./src/app/app/img/img.service.ts
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in '/Users/user/Projects/A4/imageSearch/src/app/app/img'
2. ERROR in src/app/app/img/img.service.ts(21,9): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Comment: have you updated rxjs version to the 6 as well ?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: I don't know the version of rxjs , but today only I have started this Angular 6 project by "ng new file_name"  so might be rxjs file in Node folder  is updated

Comment: It seem map is not properly imported in your code.

Comment: how I can update rxjs in Angular 6

Comment: You don't need to update it, you're already using it. *That's why you have errors.* You need to write code that is compliant with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced similar problem with `rxjs` `map` operator. Currently I'm using Angular 6. To know which version you are using:

```
ng --version
```

or

```
ng -v
```

If you are also using angular 6, then please checkout [https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/%20%20Different%20internal%20structure%20that%20requires%20you%20to%20change%20your%20import%20statements%20pipe()%20as%20a%20method%20to%20chain%20your%20operators,%20the%20old%20way%20of%20chaining%20them%20will%20not%20work)

1. Different internal structure that requires you to change your import statements
2. pipe() as a method to chain your operators, the old way of chaining them will not work

Let's say you use map for `http.get` method:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

private url = "some site...";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForecast() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(map(result => result));
  }
```

**NOT:** `this.http.get(this.url).map(result => result);`

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation @nodirabegimxonoyim

Comment: @kronus you are welcome. I am glad if it was helpful

Answer (score 4):

This is how we can import observable and map in rxjs 6

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Answer (score 0):

Run command in your package.

npm install --save rxjs-compat

And import below line in your file.

import 'rxjs-compat';

Answer (score -1):

With rxjs 6, import path is changed.
Please import operator like this

1. import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
2. import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

Hope it will work.