# Angular 6: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: dictionary, rxjs, http-get, angular6

I am doing https://coursetro.com/posts/code/126/Let's-build-an-Angular-5-Chart.js-App---Tutorial

and facing some problems. 
Currently I am using:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.4.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.0.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

In, ***weather.service.ts*** if I want to use

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForecast() {
    return this._http.get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22").map(result => result);
  }
}
```

but it's giving me an error:

---

(Browser console)

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

---

(Terminal)

ERROR in ./src/app/weather.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/map' in '/home/nodira/AngularProjects/charts/src/app'

---

I tried the following with solution give in [Angular 6 : where getting error module "rxjs/add/operator/map" and another error 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837367/angular-6-where-getting-error-module-rxjs-add-operator-map-and-another-error):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  dailyForecast() {
    return this._http.get("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22").pipe(map(result => result));
  }
}
```

Now I am not getting any error in terminal, but I don't see any desired [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6npb9.png) in console of browser neither. 
I had similar `Can't resolve rxjs/add/operator/filter` when I wanted to use `filter` error when I wanted. I would really appreciate your help.
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Where is the code that would you expect to perform the actual console.log()?

Comment: It is in app.component:

 `constructor(private _weather: WeatherService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._weather.dailyForecast().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);

    })
  }`
I am injecting weather.service into app.comonent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out some reasons of error messages I provided above. The reason of error with `rxjs` was declaring map function wrongly. This link has some info about declaration changes: https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/

1. Different internal structure that requires you to change your import
   statements
2. pipe() as a method to chain your operators, the old way of chaining
   them will not work

Also, I think about the reason of not getting result from `http request`. I think it may be because `http://samples.openweathermap.org` blocked `http://localhost:4200/` for `http requests` like `get`.

---

Seems I found a solution as long as project works. When I added proxy backend problem with http get solved. For more detailed information about Proxy backend please check: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md). Sharing solution here in case somebody faces the same problem:

Add a `proxy.conf.json file` at the same level as `package.json`. It should could look like this:

```
{
"/api": {
"target": "http://samples.openweatherm...",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {
"^/api": ""
},
"changeOrigin": true
}
}
```

Update this in the service.

```
dailyForecast() {
return this._http.get("/api/data/2.5/history/city?q=Warren,OH&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22")
.map(result => result);
}
```

Serve with this command.

`ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json`

Feel free to see the code of project provided these problems :) in this  [link](https://github.com/NodiraIbrogimova/angular-5-and-6-chart.js)

Comment: proxy-config proxy.conf.json is not for production

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't come from the app client, if you want to fix it definitively, you have to solve at the backend side

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @BlueLike Thank you for the answer. I understand what you mean. But, the backend of the website I mentioned above iis not under my authority. So, I cannot fix it from backend as you mean.

Comment: your backend langage is java??