# Anuglar 6 .post .subscribe inserting record twice

Tags: php, mysql, angular, api

I am trying to put an Angular 6 CRUD together. My addCoins method seems to be adding the record twice.

```
addCoin(name, price) {
const obj = {
  name: name,
  price: price
};

const uri = 'http://localhost/ng6crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

this
  .http
  .post(uri, obj)
  .subscribe(res =>
    console.log('Done'));
}
```

I have created a simple PHP api that sits in the ng6crud directory. The following is the code for the api/post-coins/ - If I use postman to post to the API, then it only inserts the data once.

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
$elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes

global $name, $price;

if(!empty($elements[3]))
{
  $name = $elements[3];
}

if(!empty($elements[4]))
{
  $price = $elements[4];
}

global $server;
$server = "localhost";
global $user;
$user = "someU";
global $pwd;
// $pwd = "someP"; // production
 $pwd = "someP"; // local
global $db;
$db = "someDb";

 //open connection to mysql db
$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd,$db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

//fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "INSERT into coins (name, price) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $price . "')";

// echo $sql;
// die();

if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   // echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
   // echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
}

$connection->close();
?>
```

The combination of an .htaccess file and the "" tag in the httpd-vhosts.conf file allows the api/post-coins/ to accept two parameters for "name" and "price" to be included in the sql insert statement - for example api/post-coins/rupple/1.00 would insert a row into the db.

The following is the .htaccess file:

```
    IndexIgnore * # prevent directory listing

Order deny,allow
Allow from *

# ------------------------------------------
# Rewrite so that php extentions are not shown
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]
```

The following is the Location tag within the "" tag in the httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
    <Location /post-coins>
        ForceType appllication/x-http-php
    </Location>
```

Once more, if I use postman to post to api/post-coins/rupple/1.00 then only one entry will be in the db. When using the service within Angular 6, it is inserting the data twice. I have tried removing the .subscribe, but then nothing is inserted and I have tried to remove the two parameters at the end of the URL, but that results is two empty entries.

Thanks in advance

To answer @Vikas question as to how I implement, the following is the create.component.html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    {{ title }}
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Coin Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" #name />
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].invalid && (angForm.controls['name'].dirty || angForm.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['name'].errors.required">
          Name is required.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4">Coin Price</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="price" #price/>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['price'].invalid && (angForm.controls['price'].dirty || angForm.controls['price'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div *ngIf="angForm.controls['price'].errors.required">
          Price is required.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button (click)="addCoin(name.value, price.value)" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The creat.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CoinService } from '../../service/coin.service';
import { FormGroup,  FormBuilder,  Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create',
  templateUrl: './create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create.component.css']
})
export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Add Coin';
  angForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private coinservice: CoinService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ],
      price: ['', Validators.required ]
    });
  }
  addCoin(name, price) {
    this.coinservice.addCoin(name, price);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And the coin.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class CoinService {

  result: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addCoin(name, price) {
    const obj = {
      name: name,
      price: price
    };

    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

    this
      .http
      .post(uri, obj)
      .subscribe(res =>
        console.log('Done'));
  }

  getCoins() {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/get-coins/';
    return this
              .http
              .get(uri);
  }

  editCoin(id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/get-coins-id/' + id;
    return this
              .http
              .get(uri);
  }

  updateCoin(name, price, id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/put-coins/' + id;

    const obj = {
      name: name,
      price: price
    };
    this
      .http
      .post(uri, obj)
      .subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }

  deleteCoin(id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/delete-coins/' + id;

    return this
              .http
              .get(uri);
  }
}
```

And the routerConfig.ts

```
    import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateComponent } from './components/create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from './components/edit/edit.component';
import { IndexComponent } from './components/index/index.component';
import { DeleteComponent } from './components/delete/delete.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create',
    component: CreateComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'edit/:id',
    component: EditComponent
  },
  { path: 'index',
    component: IndexComponent
  },
  { path: 'delete/:id',
    component: DeleteComponent
  }
];
```

@Debojyoti, I just saw your response. I ended up creating the following, which returned nothing, but I took a look in network panel - see screen shot below:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

addCoin(name, price) {
  const obj = {
    name: name,
    price: price
  };

  const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

  this
    .http
    .post(uri, obj)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError) // then handle the error
    )
    .subscribe(res =>
      console.log('Done'));
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // return an observable with a user-facing error message
  return throwError(
    'Something happened; please try again later.');
};
```

[image: See attached screen shot]

Comment: Are you subscribing twice? share code where you are invoking your method

Comment: @Vikas, I have added the code and, to answer your question, I do not think I am subscribing it twice. At least, I do not see it in my code being called twice

Comment: While sending the add request, can you please check browsers xhr request status?
To check how many requests are being sent by angular @kronus

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools, (for chrome, press ctrl+shift+i ).
Then check network -> xhr request.
Try to add while the dev tools are open. The xhr requests will appear in that pannel @kronus

Comment: Please view my edits @Debojyoti and thank you

Comment: I have answered. Please check @kronus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out and I thank each of you for helping me to step through it over and over again.

Since my PHP API is, for all intensive purposes a "GET":

```
const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;
```

Then calling a "POST" function would fire off the API twice - see attached screen shot below:

```
const obj = {
  name: name,
  price: price
};

const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

this
  .http
  .post(uri, obj)
```

So, I changed it to a "GET" function and it works perfectly, with only one entry

```
addCoin(name, price) {
    const obj = {
      name: name,
      price: price
    };

    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

    this
      .http
      .get(uri)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
        map(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(res =>
        console.log('Done'));
  }
```

[image: only one entry]

Through this journey, I discovered from ([another stackoverflow post - see @nodirabegimxonoyim 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837367/angular-6-where-getting-error-module-rxjs-add-operator-map-and-another-error)), that map is imported differently in Angular 6 and used differently within the .get method

Instead of importing with

```
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

You use the following:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Instead of .get().map()

```
  this
  .http
  .get(uri)
  .map(res => {console.log(res)});
```

You use map, within .pipe

```
this
  .http
  .get(uri)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
    map(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  )
```

All together, the following is my new working coin.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class CoinService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addCoin(name, price) {
    const obj = {
      name: name,
      price: price
    };

    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/post-coins/' + name + '/' + price;

    this
      .http
      .get(uri)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
        map(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(res =>
        console.log('Done'));
  }

  getCoins() {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/get-coins/';
    return this
              .http
              .get(uri)
              .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
                map(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                })
              );
  }

  editCoin(id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/get-coins-id/' + id;
    return this
              .http
              .get(uri)
              .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
                map(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                })
              );
  }

  updateCoin(name, price, id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/put-coins/' + id;

    const obj = {
      name: name,
      price: price
    };
    this
      .http
      .post(uri, id)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
        map(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(res => console.log('Done'));
  }

  deleteCoin(id) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost/ng5crud/api/delete-coins/' + id;

    return this
              .http
              .get(uri)
              .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError), // then handle the error
                map(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                })
              );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something happened; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

Seriously, thank you for all your help. This takes me back to the early nineties, when programmers were nice and we would help each other.

Comment: Cool. Also, yes the import method of RxJS operators changed in 5.5 and the import paths were simplified in RxJS 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the PHP application and Angular application are running on a separate combination of protocol (http/https), domain, and port. I see the CORS headers have been added in the PHP code.

This leads me to believe 2 requests are being made, one to see if the request is allowed according to CORS (an `OPTIONS`) request and the normal `POST` request. Hence, the record being inserted twice. You could detect the request method and return the CORS headers and set the response body to nothing as appropriate on the CORS `OPTIONS` request and do an insert on a `POST` request similar to the following (not tested).

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['method'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    exit;
}

if ($_SERVER['method'] === 'POST') {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    $path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');    // Trim leading slash(es)
    $elements = explode('/', $path);                // Split path on slashes

    global $name, $price;

    if (!empty($elements[3])) {
        $name = $elements[3];
    }

    if (!empty($elements[4])) {
        $price = $elements[4];
    }

    global $server;
    $server = "localhost";
    global $user;
    $user = "someU";
    global $pwd;
    // $pwd = "someP"; // production
    $pwd = "someP"; // local
    global $db;
    $db = "someDb";

    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "INSERT into coins (name, price) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $price . "')";

    // echo $sql;
    // die();

    if ($connection->query($sql) === true) {
        // echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        // echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
    }

    $connection->close();

    exit;
}

header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @chris-mcknight,  Everything you said made so much sense, but it still inserted twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make php not to accept the first pre flight request (OPTIONS)

Just modify your php code like

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "OPTIONS") {
    $path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'); // Trim leading slash(es)
    $elements = explode('/', $path); // Split path on slashes

    global $name, $price;

    if (!empty($elements[3])) {
        $name = $elements[3];
    }

    if (!empty($elements[4])) {
        $price = $elements[4];
    }

    global $server;
    $server = "localhost";
    global $user;
    $user = "someU";
    global $pwd;
    // $pwd = "someP"; // production
    $pwd = "someP"; // local
    global $db;
    $db = "someDb";

    //open connection to mysql db
    $connection = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pwd, $db) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //fetch table rows from mysql db
    $sql = "INSERT into coins (name, price) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $price . "')";

    // echo $sql;
    // die();

    if ($connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        // echo "Record updated successfully";
    } else {
        // echo "Error updating record: " . $connection->error;
    }

}

$connection->close();
?>
```